# Webspher Deployment using terminal

Tags: deployment, terminal, websphere, ear

I am trying to learn how to deploy ear files in WebSphere v 7 using terminal,
I know how to deploy ear files using administration console but I want to learn how to deploy using terminal.

my searches did not help

Any advice

Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [AdminApp](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminapp.html?resultof=%22AdminApp%22%20%22adminapp%22%20) object in [wsadmin](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_script.html?resultof=%22wsadmin%22%20)